# Positioning my table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've been looking for a way to position one of my tables that has an image in it. Its a little bit far to the left and I need to scoot it over to the right. So far my table is written like:

```
<TD>
<IMG SRC='http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7209/6978440877_10b1fcffc4_o.jpg'/> 
</TD>
```

What do I need to add? I tried some css like:

```
position:absolute; z-index:2; left: 50px; top: 1040px;
```

-but it just appeared on the page as text. What should I add/write so that I can control where I put my table?

Comment: You may want to start with some beginner CSS Tutorials like the one on w3schools - http://www.w3schools.com/css/

Comment: Or instead of w3schools some of these resources http://w3fools.com/#what-should-be-done such as the wonderful MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs

Comment: if you have written your html and css exactly in the way you have done it here, then it can't work out.

Comment: @user1266068 - do not use w3chools.com (to understand look at w3fools).  Why are you using a table?  Unless it is to display data this is not a good design choice as the styling is very inflexible.

Comment: You might want to look at [JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 1):

When you make a table in HTML you at least need to define the table, rows, and cells (not sure if you had these already, just posting truncated code):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> ... </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When you define CSS it needs to be in the proper place. You have a few choices. First, you can put it inline in a tag like this:

```
<table style="attribute:value; attribute:value;">
```

Or you can define it in the `<head>` (preferred):

```
<head>
...
<style type="text/css">
table{
  attribute:value;
  attribute:value;

}
</style>
</head>
```

Finally, that 1000 pixel offset is pretty high. Get comfortable with both relative and absolute positioning. Absolute positioning can lead to a lot of issues for beginners who don't understand how layouts flow together in my experience.

Hopefully that will get you started. There are a lot of great resources out there.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following style for `<Body>` and `<TD>` tag it will remove the left space.

```
<body style="margin:0; padding:0;">
<TD style="padding-left:0;" >
```

If still unable to fix, please provide the complete code.

[image: After]

[image: Before]